# How do I view all records with data source as 1 if not 1 then use data source 2 but no duplicates

Tags: sql

I have a table that has the below columns

```
sk_item_id  item_code       item_desc                    sk_data_source
1           054486900       TRIM lh hotplate Whi                1
2           054486900       TRIM lh hotplate Whi                2
3           081423698       ARC3084 DG FRIT                     2
4           081744900       HANDBOOK<600G MK2>44PGX500          1
```

I want to display the records that are contained within data source 2 but if the record does not sit in data source 2 then display the record that is in data source 1 but I do not want any duplicates

so basically display all data from data source 2 if the item code is not in data source 2 then display the record

Comment: It might help if, instead of your rather roundabout description, you give an example of your desired output in the form of rows.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` with a `case` expression to prioritise rows with `sk_data_source = 2`:

```
with cte as (
  select *, 
    row_number() over(partition by item_code, item_desc 
      order by case when sk_data_source = 2 then 1 else 2 end) rn 
  from 
    table_name
) 
select 
  sk_item_id, 
  item_code, 
  item_desc, 
  sk_data_source 
from cte 
where rn = 1;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f26dffb0fb71045a8cf5115afba5a728)

Comment: Thank you much appreciated for your help

Answer (score 0):

If using Postgresql, do `DISTINCT ON`:

```
select distinct on (item_code) sk_item_id, item_code, item_desc, sk_data_source 
from table_name
order by item_code, sk_data_source desc;
```